# Why form does not load the second time i visit the user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a form and in the form I am adding and removing user controls depending on what is selected. There is a form that has two labels, the labels information is supposed to change when the user control loads but it never changes, it keeps the same values. Now, I added a break point on the load of the user control.. and it is only hit once, all the other times it just navigates there but never loads again..

```
private void SummaryScreen_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSavingsBalance.Text = Global.Instance.Accounts[1].AccountBalace.ToString();
    lblCheckingBalance.Text = Global.Instance.Accounts[0].AccountBalace.ToString();
}
```

How can I make it so that it loads all the time when i call this user control?

Comment: You are talking about the UserControl's OnLoad?  (UserControl is called SummaryScreen?)

Comment: yes the user control is called SummaryScreen - yes onload of SummaryScreen it only gets hit once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserControl.Load` is only called the first time it is added to a form after construction.

You will need to either:

- Recreate the control each time (therefore forcing Load to be called)
- Add a new method on the UserControl (like Initialize) and call it after adding

Answer (score 0):

probably it is caching 
use :-

```
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
```

in your load function